# How to create playlists of local media files without relying on paths?

Tags: audio, music, metadata, media-player, playlists

I'd like to create playlists of locally stored media files, and synchronize these playlists between my devices (desktop/laptop/phone.) However, there's one major point of friction: due to some changes in how I've stored my media library over the years, the file paths are not necessarily the same across all of my devices. Common file formats (e.g. `.fpl`, `.m3u`, `.pls`, `.wpl`) which rely on the exact path of the file are therefore unsuitable.

In almost all cases, the location where the media is rooted will differ between devices. Some media players are smart enough to work around this, and simply match on the suffix of the file. For example, if I have `D:\Music\Example Artist\Example Song.mp3` in the playlist, a music player might recognize `$SOME_ANDROID_IDENTIFIER/AndroidMusic/Example Artist/Example Song.mp3` as matching the entry. Changing the root of the library is also somewhat simple with a text editor if the music player is not sufficiently smart.

However, this strategy usually isn't robust enough to survive more complex differences in the path. If the playlist instead contains `D:\Music\Example Artist\Example Song.flac` or `D:\Music\Example Artist\Example Artist feat. Someone Else - 1-01 Example Song (2021).mp3`, the find-and replace becomes much more complex, to the point of becoming untenable for a large library.

My ideal solution to this problem would be a file format that is based on metadata. Instead of containing the precise path of the file, it might instead contain something like the following JSON:

```
{
  songs: [
    {
      artist: "Example Artist",
      title: "Example Song"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since I can guarantee the stability of the basic metadata between re-encodings, renamings, and copyings, this should allow any media player to match on the provided metadata, assuming that it can index all media files on my device.

---

*The question:* Does a file format in the vein of what I've described above exist? If not, is there any solution for creating playlists without relying on exact paths or find-and-replaces? (For my specific case, I'm concerned with interoperability between foobar2000 on Windows and Poweramp on Android, but solutions that don't use these apps are also welcome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the best existing file format that does this is the [XML Shareable Playlist Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Shareable_Playlist_Format), XSPF for short. Unfortunately, it doesn't look to be widely supported. It appears that it's primarily used within the IPTV community, but has seen little adoption when it comes to audio players.

There is a [plugin for foobar2000](https://github.com/Chocobo1/foo_xspf_1/) which adds support, but I can't find anything terribly meaningful for Poweramp or other music players on Android. Some services, such as Soundiiz, appear to have the capability to [export to XSPF](https://soundiiz.com/tutorial/export-spotify-to-xspf) from streaming services.

Answer (score 0):

.m3u, and probably other playlists, require *no* path, *just the filename*, **if the .m3u and files are in the same folder**.

That said, this does not seem to work for a *relative* path to subfolders, nor to a parent folder. [Perhaps this is application or files-system dependent; I tried using "dot", "dot-dot", forward and backward slashes to no avail under Windows/NTSF.]